# How can i seperate containers so they dont overlap on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I finished building a horizontal scrolling website, took forever to get everything lined up properly and for the scrolling to move it sideways. now ive noticed that when on mobile, some items are overlapping each other. ive tried many different codes to get them to where they should be on mobile, but then theyre not in place on computer. how can i stop these container divs from overlaping?

my site that this is happening most on is http://padmorejordan.com/about%20me.html

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

#sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(17,16,17,.80);
    left:-200px;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 0px;
}


#sidebar ul li{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,1.00)
}


#sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 230px;
    top: 20px;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn span {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #151719;
    margin: 3px 0px;
}

*{
    margin: 0px;
}


html, body{
    height:100%;
}

.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(244,244,244,1.00);
}


.surroundContainer{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
}

.surroundContainer p{
    color:rgba(244,244,244,1.00);
}
.Hpage{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 
    background-color:rgba(244,244,244,1.00);
}
.pageHome{
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:rgba(244,244,244,1.00) ;
}


#img1{
    float: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
}
#img2{
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
}

.pageHome{
    margin: auto;
    height: 99%;
    width: 99%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:rgba(244,244,244,1.00) ;
}

.textpage{
    margin-top: auto;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    display: inline-block;
 
    background-color: rgba(245,245,245,1.00);
 
}

#img1{
    float: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
}
#img2{
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
}

#paragraph{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: block;
}

.table{
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}



.barpage{
    height: 78%;
    width: 78%;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%; 
}


.skillbar {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    height:35px;
 
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition:0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition:0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition:0.4s linear;
    -o-transition:0.4s linear;
    transition:0.4s linear;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition-property:width, background-color;
    -moz-transition-property:width, background-color;
    -ms-transition-property:width, background-color;
    -o-transition-property:width, background-color;
    transition-property:width, background-color;
}

.skillbar-title {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:110px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background:#6adcfa;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

.skillbar-title span {
    display:block;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding:0 20px;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

.skillbar-bar {
    height:35px;
    width:0px;
    background:#6adcfa;
 
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.skill-bar-percent {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:0;
    font-size:11px;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    color:#ffffff;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

td{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 900px;
    text-align: center;
}
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
 
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 900px;
 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-indent: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    word-spacing: 2px;
}

h2{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Jordan Padmore | About page</title>

<meta name="description" content="Hi, I'm Jordan Padmore, a Graphic and Motion Designer who specializes in learning and executing new creative strategies in fastest possible time. From advertising and branding to motion graphics and web design or coding, i have learned it all.">

<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript,Graphic Designer, Graphic Design Portfolio,Padmore,Jordan,Art,Gallery,About,Video,Motion Graphics,Contact,Scangift,Luminart,Ledology,A90sKid,Raincoast Dog Rescue,Basketball,Undertales,Adobe,Photoshop,Illustrator,Indesign,Cinema4D,Dreamweaver,Wordpress,Toronto,Ontario,Canada,Canadian,Artist">

<meta name="Content-Type" content="http://padmorejordan.com/images/5.jpg">

<meta name="twitter:card" value="summary"> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta property="og:title" content="Jordan Padmore | Independant Graphic And Motion Designer Portfolio" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.padmorejordan.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://padmorejordan.com/images/5.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Hi, I'm Jordan Padmore, a Graphic and Motion Designer who specializes in learning and executing new creative strategies in fastest possible time. From advertising and branding to motion graphics and web design or coding, i have learned it all." /> 




<script>
 function toggleSidebar(){
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle('active');
  
  
 }
 
 </script>
<link rel="icon" type="images/png" href="images/jp-logo.png"/>
<link href="AboutMe.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
 
<script>
$(function() {
 $("html, body, *").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
  this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 80);
  this.scrollRight -= (delta * 80);
  event.preventDefault();
 });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="sidebar">
 <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  
 </div>
 
 <a href="index.html"><img src="images/gallery/logo-idea-3.png"></a>
 <ul>
  <a href="home page.html"><li>
  Home
  </li></a>
  <a href="Gallery.html"><li>
  Gallery
  </li></a> 
  <a href="Video.html"><li>
  Videos
  </li></a>
  <a href="about.html"><li>
  About 
  </li></a>
  <a href="contact.html"><li>
  Contact 
  </li></a>
  
 </ul>
 
</div>

 <!--wrapper for entire page-->
   <div class="wrapper">
    <!--home view portion-->
   <!--<div class="view"></div>-->
    <!-- div that will contain horizontal scroll items-->
    <div class="surroundContainer">
     <div class="pageHome">
       <h4><img id="img2" src="images/block-lettering.png" width="30%">
         <img id="img1" src="images/me2.png" width="40%">
         
         
         </h4>
     </div>
     <div class="textpage">
         
    <table class="table" style="border: 1px solid rgba(124,124,124,1.00)" >
     
     <tr>
      
      <td>
       
       
       
 <h2>HI, MY NAME IS JORDAN PADMORE</h2>
<pre>
 I am an up and coming force in the field of Graphic Design. Born and raised in Toronto, Ontario, I learned to appreciate art and structure from the media and artwork found throughout the city. I love to create eye-catching graphic designs, whether its 2D art in Photoshop and Illustrator, 3D in Cinema 4D, or motion graphics in After Effects. My specialty from graduating George Brown College is in Advertising design, but have developed other skills in medias and design aspects, such as web design, landscape and interior design, story boarding, photography, and branding. Some of my latest work for clients includes the creation of innovative app ideas, building interactive exciting websites for companies in Italy, and developing title sequences for TV and YouTube web shows. In my free time, you can catch me snowboarding in the mountains, biking through the city, or just fishing all year round, even if I have to break through ice. I'm a hard-working, focused individual who believes being passionate about your work and drive to finish a project is a must have. <a href="contact.html">Contact me</a> to see what I can do to help bring your advertising, branding, and web design needs to life.
             </pre>
      </td>
     </tr>
     
    </table>
     
     </div>
          
          
       <div class="barpage">
          
     <div class="Skill bars">
     
     <h1>Working Skills</h1>

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="100%">
 <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #3498db;"><span>Photoshop</span></div>
 <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background:rgba(65,159,223,1.00);"></div>
 <div class="skill-bar-percent">100%</div>
</div> <!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="90%">
 <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #e67e22;"><span>Illustrator</span></div>
 <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background:rgba(244,153,73,1.00);"></div>
 <div class="skill-bar-percent">90%</div>
</div> <!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="85%">
 <div class="skillbar-title" style="background:rgba(123,66,199,1.00)"><span>Indesign</span></div>
 <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background:rgba(68,6,96,1.00)"></div>
 <div class="skill-bar-percent">85%</div>
</div> <!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="80%">
 <div class="skillbar-title" style="background:rgba(203,37,73,1.00)"><span>After Effects</span></div>
 <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background:rgba(140,13,41,1.00)"></div>
 <div class="skill-bar-percent">80%</div>
</div> <!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="75%">
 <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #4288d0;"><span>Wordpress</span></div>
 <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #124e8c;"></div>
 <div class="skill-bar-percent">75%</div>
</div> <!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="60%">
 <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #27ae60;"><span>HTML CSS</span></div>
 <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #2ecc71;"></div>
 <div class="skill-bar-percent">60%</div>
</div> <!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="60%">
 <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #124e8c;"><span>Cinema 4D</span></div>
 <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #4288d0;"></div>
 <div class="skill-bar-percent">60%</div>
</div> 
       

    </div>
     </div>
          
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. It would also be helpful if you show what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1):

For responsive design first set viewPort in your HTML page and use bootstrap

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In bootstarp no need to manually define the position and width of div.[BootStap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)

Comment: i added the code to the site, but it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: @jordanpadmore with out bootstrap you have to write lot more css  for responsive its better than use bootstarp its very simple.